Annotation for unit testing service layer in isolation
For testing controller in isolation we have @WebmvcTest available in spring boot test.
It would only configure controller class and no dependencies for it. Similarly for jpa layer we have @DatajpaTest
Is there something similar for service beans?

Just unit test them, no need for spring context.
DataJpa and SpringWeb are PARTS of spring therfore you have to boot it up to have reliable tests that includes all Spring behaviors into the equasion
Service layer on the other hand, are just POJOs, so unit testing those are the easiest and most straightforward of all.
PS. just dont use field injection but via constructor and/or via setters and you will be fine.

One of the dependency for service bean needs freemarker configured. Not sure if that would work without spring context?

You just mock it out like you normally do in unit testing righ? BTW freemarker is part of "view" therfore it should be part of controller logic.

It soulds like you dont want to have unit tests (bad) at all but rather integration tests. Then you configure the context yourself disabling web server and mocking out persistance (or not and using inmemory h2)

I am not using @SpringBootTest, so not sure if its integration testing. I am under impression that with annotations mentioned in post we do unit testing, isn't?

No, those are all integration tests, but that is the way to test those parts. You can always unit test controller like any other pojo, but it will not take into the account all spring stuff that sits on top of it mapping, content negotiation, security, setup blablabla. But inner logic still can be unit tested.
